# "Ich and "mich" in this sub-clause

Tags: german-to-english, passive

I have a question in this sentence:

> Ich wusste ja nicht, was mich da erwarten würde.

Why in the subordinate clause I have not used "Ich" instead of "mich"?

I do not get the meaning of the sentence, it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ich" and "mich" in that sentence with different meanings and they are exactly the same in english:

> Ich wusste ja nicht, was **mich** da erwarten würde.
>
> --> I didn't know what would expect **me** there.

---

> Ich wusste ja nicht, was **ich** da erwarten würde.
>
> --> I didn't know what **I** would expect there.

Answer (score 1):

**"Ich"** is nominative case (**"I"**), **"Mich"** is accusative case (**"me"**).

I think your confusion stems from the verb *"erwarten"*. The primary translation (that you might have looked up in the dictionary) is *"to expect"*. However, this meaning is slightly figurative. Literally, *"erwarten"* means *"to await"*.

*"Expect"* works smoothly as a translation if a person is doing the "erwarten":

> German: **jemand** (subject -> nominative) *erwartet* **jemanden** or
>   **etwas** (both cases: object -> accusative).
>
> English: **someone** (subject) *expects/awaits* **someone** or **something** (both cases: object).

The figurative meaning is almost too obvious to even notice that it's not exactly literal (you don't have to physically wait to expect something, after all).

However, in English, only **someones** can *"expect"*, not **somethings** (because anticipation is an expression of sentience). So if you want to swap subject and object around (and you can, German is pretty liberal in that regard), *"to expect"* doesn't work anymore and you have to use the literal translation, which is *"to await"*.

> German: **etwas** (subject -> nominative) *erwartet* **jemanden** (object -> accusative).
>
> English: **something** (subject) *awaits* (not: *expects*) **someone** (object).

This is what happens in your example. Unfortunately, **"was"** looks the same in both nominative and accusative case, so both variants are a bit difficult to tell apart. But **"mich"** has to be the object (it's in accusative form), and from that you can disambiguate the rest of the sentence.